# Fetching the start time and end time from the meeting to task pane outlook addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

i am trying to set the end time and start time from meeting to taskpane, for this I have used
office js api addHandlerAsync

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-addhandlerasync-member(1)

[image]

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.AppointmentTimeChanged, function (result:any) {
    debugger
    const items = Office.context.mailbox.item;

    items.start.getAsync( async function (result) {
      const updatedStartTime = await getMeetingTime(result.value);
     setMeetingSchedule({ ...meetingSchedule, startTime: `${updatedStartTime.toLocaleLowerCase()}` });
    
    });
    items.end.getAsync( async function (result) {
      const updatedEndTime = await getMeetingTime(result.value);
     setMeetingSchedule({ ...meetingSchedule, endTime: `${updatedEndTime.toLocaleLowerCase()}` });
    });
  });
```

only endTime has change and the component rerender multiple times i have tried this code in useEffect but still rendering

Comment: Where is the exact problem - getting the start time using OfficeJS or updating the task pane UI? Could you try to separate these pieces and try to get the start time without updating the UI? Does it work correctly?

Comment: yes with `   setMeetingSchedule((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, endTime: `${updatedEndTime.toLocaleLowerCase()}` };
          }); 
`
i have solved the problem @Eugene Astafiev

Answer (score 1):

On the screenshot I see the start time is still focused on the UI. The Office JavaScript API (the Outlook object model) may not fire events until the focus is moved to another field on the UI or the item is saved. This is a known issue when dealing with the Outlook object model or Office JavaScript API.

Comment: thanks for your response @EugeneAstafiev issue has been resolved.